# Nim application refuses to run on heroku

Tags: heroku, nim-lang

I'm using the nim buildpack to run a simple jester server on heroku. However, the asyncnet library sometimes refuses to use the port heroku provides (different each time). Here's what happens if nim doesn't like the port:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
macros.nim(293)          blog
jester.nim(326)          serve
asyncdispatch.nim(282)   asyncCheck
asyncdispatch.nim(224)   callback=
asyncdispatch.nim(286)   :anonymous
Error: unhandled exception: value ot of range: 58622 [Exception]

Original stack trace in serve:
Traceback (most recent call last)
macros.nim(293)          blog
jester.nim(326)          serve
asyncdispatch.nim(1212)  serve
asyncdispatch.nim(1199)  cb
asyncnet.nim(433)        bindAddr
asynchttpserver.nim(250) serveIter

Continuing...
```

(I'm sure that 58622 is the port heroku is trying to feed the program.) When I run locally with port 58622, the server works fine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you stumbled on a bug in Nim's socket code. The good news is that it is already fixed in the devel version of the compiler on [Github](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/lib/pure/asyncnet.nim#L452), in 0.11.2 it was broken [here](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/master/lib/pure/asyncnet.nim#L433). My guess is that on Heroku you are using Nim 0.11.2 which is the latest release and on your local computer you are using the devel version which does not have this bug.

In any case, the solution should be to update the version of Nim that heroku uses.

Comment: This is consistent with my experience, but how would I go about updating Nim on heroku? Setting the version to >=0.11.3 in the nimble file and setting the branch to devel (as per heroku-buildpack-nim's instructions) doesn't work (heroku rejects the build)